# Make a character thinner

Tags: arrays, braces, delimiters

With the following LaTeX code, the braces look too thick when the `array` is large. Is it possible to make the brace thinner? By the way, the `|` delimiters look always good.

```
\[\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right. \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A+B=C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right. \]

\[\left|\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right|\quad
\left|\begin{array}{l}
A+B+C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right| \]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because other fotns are not wanted, the brace symbol can also be drawn by TikZ. It even provides a decoration with a brace:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand*{\thinbraceleft}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      decoration=brace,
      inner sep=0pt,
    ]
      \node (M) {$\displaystyle #1$};
      \draw[decorate] (M.south west) -- (M.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\[\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right. \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A+B=C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right. \]

\[
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      A+B=C\\J+K=L
    \end{array}
  \right.
  \quad
  \thinbraceleft{
    \begin{array}{l}
      A+B=C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
    \end{array}
  }
\]

\[\left|\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right|\quad
\left|\begin{array}{l}
A+B+C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right| \]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

You can use  different fonts, e.g. these offered by the package `mnsymbol`. But beware: this package makes other changes in appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\begin{document}

\[\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right. \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A+B=C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right. \]

\[\left|\begin{array}{l}
 A+B=C\\J+K=L
\end{array}\right|\quad
\left|\begin{array}{l}
A+B+C\\J+K=L\\O+P=Q\\R+S=T\\U+V=W\\X+Y=Z
\end{array}\right| \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I could not use other fonts for some reasons.