# How do I get less thick matrix lines?

Tags: matrices, bold

Currently for my column vectors they look like this:

[image]

I want them to look like this:

[image]

Right now I'm using the lgroup/rgroup symbols to get them the right curliness, but I can't get them to be the right "boldness", my current code follows.

```
\left\lgroup\begin{matrix} 1 \\2 \end{matrix}\right\rgroup+\lambda\left\lgroup\begin{matrix} -1 \\3 \end{matrix}\right\rgroup
```

I looked at this response [Make a character thinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185993/make-a-character-thinner) on this website and they've used Tikz to make a new definition of a "thinbrace". Can someone help me do this with the lgroup and rgroup symbols?

For reference here are all my user packages

```
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{framed}    
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{helvet}    
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{totalcount} 
\usepackage{accents}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use package `nicematrix`, where `pNiceArray` has that shape.

Comment: why use `\lgroup` ? that is specifically to get straighter bolder brackets. remove the `\left\right` and use `\begin{pmatrix}`  to get standard ()

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I tried it and it's not curly enough, the pmatrix isn't the right shape I'm searching for sorry

Comment: Where did the image come from? If you have a pdf you can extract font information which may help.

Comment: @SandyG The screenshot came from the following pdf: https://educationstandards.nsw.edu.au/wps/wcm/connect/49c4cd12-5c7f-4969-93fd-b34b06426620/2020-hsc-mathematics-extension-2.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=ROOTWORKSPACE-49c4cd12-5c7f-4969-93fd-b34b06426620-no2PTNa.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this can be done in a standard LaTeX font. Making the group symbols thinner won't help because you will also remove some of the curliness you want. The numbers look like Times Roman, but I suspect the math is a licensed Adobe font that is not freely available.

Comment: @SandyG Ok thank you for your help :)

Comment: Could also try using kpfonts and keeping the parenthesis outside of the matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ever encountered such question too (see [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453436/how-to-make-large-brace-and-parenthesis-thinner)). In my opinion, it's not a good idea to use the `tikz` package to solve the question. I found an elegant way to change the large brace and parenthesis only, that is to **invoke such `largesymbols` from the other font file** which is already existed in the TeX system. The codes are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{framed}    
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{helvet}    
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{totalcount} 
\usepackage{accents}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{mylargesymbols}{OMX}{ccex}{m}{n}%
%change the thickness of large left and right braces 
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{mylargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{mylargesymbols}{"09}
%change the thickness of large left and right parenthesis
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{"28}{mylargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{mylargesymbols}{"01}
%change the thickness of large left and right brakets
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen}{operators}{"5B}{mylargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{operators}{"5D}{mylargesymbols}{"03}
%change the thickness of large above and under braces
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"7D}
%change the thickness of large left and right groups
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lgroup}{\mathopen}{mylargesymbols}{"3A}{largesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rgroup}{\mathclose}{mylargesymbols}{"3B}{largesymbols}{"3B}
%change the thickness of large left and right braceverts
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\bracevert}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"3E}{largesymbols}{"3E}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\huge

\[\left\lgroup\begin{matrix} 1 \\2 \end{matrix}\right\rgroup+\lambda\left\lgroup\begin{matrix} -1 \\3 \end{matrix}\right\rgroup\]

We have
    \[
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    2x^{2018}+9&x<2018;\\
    3x+2018&x\geq 2018.
    \end{cases}
    \]
    And we also have
    \[
    \left(\left\{
    \begin{array}{cc}
     x   &m  \\
     y   &n  \\
     x   &m  \\
     y   &n
    \end{array}
    \right\}\right)
    \]
    and 
    \[k\leq \langle \underbrace{a,\cdots,a,b,\cdots,b}_{a+b~\text{many}}\rangle.\]
    We don't change the thickness of any other large symbols, for example
    \[\sum^x_yx+y=\prod_y^x xy.\]

\end{document}
```

And the output is as follows.

[image]

**You can also use the other large symbol font codes instead of `ccex` as you wish, for example, the line weight produced by `llcmex` is smaller than that produced by `ccex`.**

---

By the way, please give a minimal working sample next time when you ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` has bad weight in classical 7bit Computer Modern math font, but the weight is correct when Unicode font LatinModern-Math is used. Try this:

```
\useOpTeX

Lgroup/rgroup from 7-bit CM math fonts:
$$\left\lgroup\matrix{1\cr3}\right\rgroup,
  \left(\matrix{1\cr3}\right)$$

\fontfam[lm] 
Lgroup/rgroup from LatinModern-Math, Unicode font:
$$\left\lgroup\matrix{1\cr3}\right\rgroup,
  \left(\matrix{1\cr3}\right)$$

\bye
```

[image: lgroup/rgroup]

My advice is: Use Unicode fonts.

Comment: Do you know how to apply unicode fonts on overleaf? I've put my user packages up, I'm not sure if there is a certain order I need to apply the unicode font package to and all that.

Comment: @Quippy In fact, such kinds of large symbols are created only in special mathematical packages in which it involves more than one special unicodes, and a special calculation defined in the package. So the usual fonts give no help on this.

Comment: Overleaf can run `luatex` engine (for example), if you select "LuaLaTeX" in the menu. If there is the file `latexmkrc` with the content `$lualatex = 'TEXINPUTS=./optex//:$TEXINPUTS luatex -fmt=optex %O %S';` then you can run my example above, which can be processed by the OpTeX format.

Answer (score 0):

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 2 
    \end{pmatrix}
    + \lambda 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\ 3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not give me the curliness that I want from the brackets

Comment: @Quippy Use `Bmatrix` instead of `pmatrix`